# These two sentences from a WaPo article don't sound right but are they grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> "The day Pence’s essay was published, five states were averaging more
> than 1,000 cases per day. There still are."

If the first sentence read "... there were five states averaging ..." it would sound fine to me.

For reference, the original article: https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2020/06/22/week-after-pence-bragged-about-improvement-pandemic-is-obviously-getting-worse/

Comment: They are both fine.  Consider that, “***Five states were averaging more than 1,000 cases per day***” is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: I agree that both sentences are independently grammatical. But I'm not convinced that they play well together. Your shortened first sentence paired with the second sentence as is doesn't appear to be an improvement to me. There still are _what?_ Five states that "were averaging..."? Or "five states (currenty) averaging..."? My ear tells me that the 'are' and 'were' need to coincide somehow. After a short refresher, I've relearned that the first sentence is past progressive tense. But the second isn't telling me anything about the act of averaging, only about the existence of 5 states.

Comment: There were five states then and there are still five states now.  They seem to pair well for me.

Comment: The first sentence expresses the idea that there were "five states that were averaging." So I think the required interpretation of the second is "There still are _five states that were averaging._" But that's not the intention. The intention is to say there are still five states that *are* averaging...

Comment: @JBones You haven't made it explicit what you think is wrong here. I -think- you mean 'There still are is wrong' and it should be 'They still are'. Is that correct? If so, edit you question to add this. If not... edit your question to say explicitly what you think is wrong.

Comment: It's a typo. Should have been _they_, not _there_. Probly just an echo in the writer's mind of a _there were_ that they'd just deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I have been unable to access the full article. Nonetheless, one would say  that the *there* in the second sentence is erroneous *only* in light of the preceding sentence. The correct form would read:

"*They* still are."
or
"*Those* still are."

Comment: your suggestion supposes a condition which may not be true.  The sentence only says there are five that are. It does not say that they are the same five.

Comment: The quoted text shows that the writer is comparing the average cases per day in a *particular set* of five States on two successive points of time. It is incomprehensible that after talking about particular five states in the preceding sentence, the writer would choose, without explicitly mentioning so, suddenly to talk about *another* five in the next sentence.

Comment: @Cosmopolitan - I think Jim is right on this score. Consider that a more complete second sentence would have been: "There still are five states averaging more than 1,000 cases per day." There is no necessity that it references the same five states. Only the number of states were referred to, not which states. So your answer would change the meaning.

Comment: @J Bones- Yes, speculations without examination of the source material doesn't clinch issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences are grammatical and make sense, in **the specific context of the article**. It was published by *The Washington Post* in response to former U.S. Vice President Pence.

Pence wrote an opinion piece titled [There Isn’t a Coronavirus ‘Second Wave’](https://www.wsj.com/articles/there-isnt-a-coronavirus-second-wave-11592327890) ("With testing, treatments and vaccine trials ramping up, we are far better off than the media report") via *Wall Street Journal* on 16 June 2020. Relevant excerpt, emphasis mine:

> While talk of an increase in cases dominates cable news coverage, more
> than half of states are actually seeing cases decline or remain
> stable... **in the six states that have reached more than 1,000 new
> cases a day**, increased testing has allowed public health officials
> to identify most of the outbreaks in particular settings — prisons,
> nursing homes and meatpacking facilities — and contain them.

One week later, WaPo deconstructed Pence's claim. I'm unsure if it is a fact check. The title is not neutral: [A week after Pence bragged about improvement, the pandemic is obviously getting worse](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vlMVuxt5kjcJ:https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2020/06/22/week-after-pence-bragged-about-improvement-pandemic-is-obviously-getting-worse/&cd=11&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). It is in the "Politics" section. Perhaps it is a rebuttal instead of a fact check. This is the cited passage by OP, expanded for context. Via WaPo by Phillip Bump, 22 June 2020, emphasis mine:

> The day Pence’s essay was published, **five states were averaging more
> than 1,000 cases per day. There still are.** Those states are Arizona,
> California, Florida, North Carolina and Texas. Although national daily
> case totals were once largely a function of cases in New York and New
> Jersey, the recent increase has been driven in large part by Arizona,
> Florida and Texas, which are adding between 12.5 (Texas) new cases for
> every 100,000 residents and 32.8 new cases (Arizona).

Pence said that six states reported more than 1000 new cases of COVID19 per day as of 16 June. **He did not list which states they were.** Bump responded. He informed that one week later, five states are **still** averaging more than 1000 cases per day, i.e. that the pandemic is **NOT** getting better. As of 22 June, Bump lists the five states that are reporting more than 1000 new cases of COVID19.

Bump did not source the data in the article by Pence. He used it as is: Six unknown states had 1000 or more cases per day. If the six states mentioned by Pence **DID NOT** include the states of Arizona, California, Florida, North Carolina, or Texas, Bump's wording is grammatically and contextually valid. If the six states mentioned by Pence **DID** include the five states of Arizona, California, Florida, North Carolina and Texas, Bump's wording is correct. It isn't the best way to phrase the comparison. Bump could have expanded upon the data situation and avoided the odd wording.

---

Caveats: Disregard the numerical data. We're focusing on the grammar.

Comment: Would you consider it natural to say "Yesterday, a man was sitting on a wall. There still is."? (To me that sounds wrong, and to fix it I'd change it either to "...there was a man...", or to "He still is").

Comment: @psmears I agree with you for the sentences you provided as examples. In this case, WaPo's Bump is responding to Pence saying that six unspecified states had more than 1000 cases per day. One week later, there are five specific states (for which Bump has data) that have more than 1000 cases per day.  Without knowing which states Pence was referring to, it is reasonable for Bump to say there are still five states that have 1000 cases per day. They may or may not be the same as five of the six states that Pence referred to.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I understand the situation, it's the words I have an issue with! For me, in order to say *just* "There still are.", you have to have said "There were <something>" or something similar beforehand, for it to refer back to - and that context doesn't exist here. (By contrast, it's fine to say - as you have done in your comment - "There are still five states", but "There still are" prompts the question "There still are... what?".)

Comment: @EllieKesselman - You can boil it down to an example like this: "Yesterday a fly was in my soup. There still is." The second sentence is incomplete and its subject isn't clearly linked to the preceding sentence. The meaning is decipherable (in this instance), but it isn't clear. It would be if the first sentence were "Yesterday there was a fly in my soup." Without a more explicit link between the subjects, I think it sounds awful. I don't know who the ultimate authority on grammaticality is but I think they should declare this ungrammatical if they haven't already. ;-)